# Profile option does not show up in Java VisualVM for Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jvisualvm

Using Java Visual VM I can't profile a Tomcat application. It appears correctly in the Applications  section, but the "Profile" option is missing.

The Tomcat is launched from Eclipse. My JDK version is 1.6.21. Tomcat is 6.0.29.

I tried adding the jmx remote parameters in the JVM startup, but that solutions seems to solve older problems in VirtualVM when Tomcat didn't appear as an application. That's not my case. Anyway, I tried and didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

Eclipse was configured to launch Tomcat pointing to a different JVM. Changing this in Window/Preferences/Server/Runtime Enviroment and editing my launch configuration and pointing to my installed JDK, it worked. Profile option appeared for Tomcat.